Out of memory when present new UIViewController
My app's structure is UINavigationController -> vcA -> vcB -> vcC.
When I present any view controller from vcC, memory usage keeps increasing until the app crashes due to out-of-memory issues.
However, when I present from vcA or vcB, everything works fine.
Can anyone help explain why this happens and how to fix it?
Addition:
This issue seems to occur when I use VerticalButton. I can present it normally if I remove it from the .xib file. When I use VerticalButton, the app crashes when I present from anywhere in vcC

This is code of VerticalButton

class VerticalButton: UIButton {
    
    override init(frame: CGRect) {
        super.init(frame: frame)
        configureButton()
    }
    
    required init?(coder: NSCoder) {
        super.init(coder: coder)
        configureButton()
    }

    override func awakeFromNib() {
        super.awakeFromNib()
        configureButton()
    }

    override func layoutSubviews() {
        super.layoutSubviews()
        updateButtonSize()
    }

    private func configureButton() {
        var configuration = UIButton.Configuration.plain()
        configuration.imagePlacement = .top
        configuration.imagePadding = 8
        configuration.contentInsets = NSDirectionalEdgeInsets(top: 10, leading: 10, bottom: 10, trailing: 10)

        self.configuration = configuration

        self.setContentHuggingPriority(.defaultHigh, for: .horizontal)
        self.setContentHuggingPriority(.defaultHigh, for: .vertical)
        self.setContentCompressionResistancePriority(.defaultHigh, for: .horizontal)
        self.setContentCompressionResistancePriority(.defaultHigh, for: .vertical)
    }

    func updateButtonSize() {
        guard let image = self.imageView?.image, let title = self.titleLabel?.text else { return }

        let titleSize = (title as NSString).size(withAttributes: [NSAttributedString.Key.font: self.titleLabel?.font ?? UIFont.systemFont(ofSize: 17)])
        let imageSize = image.size

        let contentHeight = imageSize.height + titleSize.height + (self.configuration?.imagePadding ?? 0)
        let contentWidth = max(imageSize.width, titleSize.width)

        let width = contentWidth + (self.configuration?.contentInsets.leading ?? 0) + (self.configuration?.contentInsets.trailing ?? 0)
        let height = contentHeight + (self.configuration?.contentInsets.top ?? 0) + (self.configuration?.contentInsets.bottom ?? 0)
        self.frame.size = CGSize(width: width, height: height)

        self.invalidateIntrinsicContentSize()
    }

    override func setTitle(_ title: String?, for state: UIControl.State) {
        super.setTitle(title, for: state)
        updateButtonSize()
    }

    override func setImage(_ image: UIImage?, for state: UIControl.State) {
        super.setImage(image, for: state)
        updateButtonSize()
    }
}

Thanks!

Can you share more code? How does a controller present from vcC? It seems like there is a memory leak here, between the presented controller and vcC.

@sonle Thanks for your comment. I have added more information, please help me check. Thanks

What is the reason for the crash? Outlets, no? And you still did not provide the related presentation code. From my perspective, it's hard to guess what's going on.

Sounds like infinite recursion. Put on pause and look at call stacks.

You are setting frame in layoutSubviews, that triggers another layoutSubviews. Looks like you don't need custom layoutSubviews at all. You need call invalidateIntrinsicContentSize in setImage and in setTitle and  calculate size in intrinsicContentSize

@NguyễnĐứcThành - what are you trying to accomplish? Your "Vertical Buttons" are using auto-layout, so they will size themselves.

@NguyễnĐứcThành - You've created an infinite loop of calls to layoutSubviews(). It's not clear what you're trying to accomplish, so change your custom class to this: https://gist.github.com/DonMag/6ebf8167481bd29363db8e2e4ccbf814 and see if you get the layout you want. If you don't, then explain/show us what you're going for.
